# Connection to mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I came to know about mongodb so I installed it on my ubuntu system. Now I want use it with php.So can some one suggest me how to save the data in mongo db and how to connect the mongo db. As I am newbie to mongo I dont have much idea.

Comment: How 'bout read the docs? They're pretty good: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php), it provides both the description the API and a lot of user provided examples.